# Unable to display an image from HTML file

Tags: html, image, display

I am trying to make a webpage using HTML, JavaScript and CSS but my image files wont display. I have my img folder in the same folder that the html file is in.
I want to display the undecorated tree and then when the user clicks the button to display the other image but it is only displaying the images alt message.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                         
<html>
<title>
Christmas
</title>
<body>
<h1>Lets decorate this chritmas tree!</h1>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('xmasTreeImage').src='decoratedtree.jpg'">Decorate the tree</button>
<img id="xmasTreeImage" alt="Can't display" src="undecoratedtree.jpg" style="width:100px">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('xmasTreeImage').src='undecoratedtree.jpg'">Take away the decorations</button>

</body>
</html>
```

update:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                         
<html>
<title>
Christmas
</title>
<body>
<h1>Lets decorate this chritmas tree!</h1>


<button onclick="document.getElementById('xmasTreeImage').src='C:\Users\Me\Documents\ChristmasWebProject/decoratedtree.jpg'">Decorate the tree</button>
<img id="xmasTreeImage" alt="Can't display" src="C:\Users\Me\Documents\ChristmasWebProject/undecoratedtree.jpg" style="width:100px">
<button onclick="document.getElementById('xmasTreeImage').src='C:\Users\Me\Documents\ChristmasWebProject/undecoratedtree.jpg'">Take away the decorations</button>

</body>
</html>
```

If i add in the exact directory it displays the images but surely there is a more efficient way to do this? Also it is not displaying anything when I click the buttons it only shows the image before I click buttons.

Comment: Here you need to check this image path .Is this properly loader or not?

Comment: Yes it is in the same directory as the HTML file @caramba

Comment: Can you open and save image for web? Doesn't happen often but check the image file permission. OR drag and drop the image to the browser, then just for trying copy/paste the path from URL in your HTML file.

Comment: you set the width already, have you set the height?

Comment: You can check in inspect element by hover on this image link.After that you need to right click and open in a new tab this image link by this you will get the idea about the path is correct or not .

Comment: @jill1993 Sorry, but you contradict yourself: in the question you claim your _image folder_ is in the same directory as your html file, now here in the comments you state the _image_ is in that folder. You have to be precise with programming questions, otherwise everything will get a _guessing game_.

Comment: @arkascha My apologies, after I made this post I got rid of the img folder and just had the images in the same folder as the HTML file.

Comment: What? Now you are using _client side paths_? Does that mean you are not using a http server, but only access the local file system with your browser?

Comment: @arkascha I am new to this, I don't understand your questions or what you're talking about. In Notepadd++ I click file -> open containing folder ->explorer and then I refresh the Chrome page when I make edits.

Comment: Sounds like you are not talking about a web page at all, but a html document local to your file system. If so, then using absolute MS-Windows paths is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to display an image by typing in the specific directory. See my question edit for code.